# Apache VirtualHost with domain and subdomain, two different folders

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I'd like to put two sites in my domain, one will be accessible by **"domain.com"** and the other by **"subdomain.domain.com"** with there own folder **"/var/www/html/domain/"** and **"/var/www/html/subdomain/"**

In order to do that I configured the virtual host that way

```
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName remi-fongaufier.fr
   Alias /postfixadmin  "/var/www/html/postfixadmin/public/"
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/remi-fongaufier/
   DirectoryIndex index.html
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName omnialib.remi-fongaufier.fr
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/omnialib/
   DirectoryIndex index.php
</VirtualHost>
```

But It seems that when I try to acces subdomain he the server try to search files in **"/var/www/html/domain/subdomain"**

Any idea to fix this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your vhost.conf is fine.

Do you check the ps_shop_url in the your database ?